# Social Engine How to add or edit menu items

Tags: php, socialengine

I am new to Social Engine. I am trying to add a custom menu item that will work with jQuery.
But I need to understand where is the file or files to edit in order to apply these changes.

Can anyone tell me how the Social Engine core is organized?

How do I find the files that control and generate the menu items?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control panel > Layouts > Menu editor and add new menu items to existing menus. From the same page you can also create new menus and later add them to any layout using the layout manager.

You should be able to add jQuery functionality to any menu by editing a suitable view file. Like if you want your jQuery to be available site wide then you can edit `application\modules\Core\layouts\scripts\default.tpl` and other layout scripts on that folder.

You can also create menu plugins. Take a look at this table on database- `engine4_core_menuitems`. You can see some menu items have corresponding classes. Find out those classes in SocialEngine and try to understand how they work. You can add conditions, small javascripts using these classes and this is recommended way to work with SocialEngine menus.

Answer (score 0):

go to admin(control panel)

> > Layput
> >     Menu Editior

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, we recommend editing menus in the Menu Editor which can be found in the Admin Panel > Layout > Menu Editor. For detailed instructions, please see: http://support.socialengine.com/questions/217/Admin-Panel-Layout-Menu-Editor

Answer (score 0):

You can view the below mentioned video URL to understand the working environment with Socialengine Menu through admin user : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Frc5U6iB_wg

need to click on Control panel then Layouts then Menu editor and add new menu items to existing menus. From the same page you can also create new menus and later add them to any layout using the layout manager.